What is Emacs doing to kill my flashing cursor?
Running GNU Emacs 29.3 on a terminal on Ubuntu 24.04.1, text mode only. For reasons unrelated to this question, I use the ssh command to connect to the Linux host from my Windows command prompt (currently my only option). When I initially ssh, my cursor is a flashing block. However, when I start Emacs, it turns to a solid block, and upon exiting it remains this way. I'm assuming Emacs is sending an ANSI escape sequence that is changing it, but I have no idea how to find out what it is. Looking at the terminfo man page, I couldn't find anything related to a solid or flashing cursor.

Do you see this when starting Emacs without an init file? If so, maybe provide a step-by-step recipe to repro it. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

I do not have an emacs init file at the moment. All I need to do is start emacs, and then exit, and the cursor remains steady.

What terminal emulator are you using?

According to the manual, for terminal emacs the cursor style is controlled by a variable visible-cursor, switching to a static cursor when its value is nil.
Using the customisation interface to change this value might solve your issue.
The Ubuntu documentation lists these steps to make the keyboard cursor blink, but it looks like a manual action you have to perform after Emacs closes.
You can also query the terminfo database for the escape sequence for cvvis (Cursor very Visible) or use the command line tool as in tput cvvis.

Default value is t (which should cause the cursor to blink). I tried setting it to nil and then suspending and restarting, but that didn't change anything.

@Swechsler If Emacs does not use the visible blinking cursor when visible-cursor is t, you might want to report a bug.
